# delete 2 duplicate database indexes created on marking a string as primary key in django with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

this very simple model created 3 separate, (and duplicate) indices in the postgres database. Is there any method to avoid duplicate indices in cases like these? or disable indexes of particular kind?

My main concern is once the size of this table increases, all operations will begin to slow down as updating 3 indexes will have its cost (compute + storage).

```py
class SavedCard(Common):
    token = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, primary_key=True
    )
```

Indexes created:

1. `prefix_savedcard_token_6c141ea4_like`
2. `prefix_savedcard_token_6c141ea4_uniq`
3. `prefix_savedcard_token_6c141ea4_pk`

Comment: Run `DROP INDEX` to get rid of them.

Comment: then it leaves the codebase in an inconsistent state, as the code definitions and database state doesn't match. trying to avoid that.